# Angular 2 srcdoc polyfill doesn't work

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, polyfills

I'm using Angular 2 with angular-cli and I want to add srcdoc polyfill to support Microsoft Edge. So:

I added to package.json    https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill

I imported `import 'srcdoc-polyfill/srcdoc-polyfill.min';` in    polyfills.ts.

I used it like:

```
 <iframe class="ticket-frame" [srcdoc]="ticket.html | htmlSafe"
                  tlIframeAutoHeight>
 </iframe>
```

By chance, if you ask me for IframeAutoHeight directive, here is the code:

```
@Directive({

  selector: '[tlIframeAutoHeight]'
})
export class IframeAutoHeightDirective {

  constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    renderer.listen(element.nativeElement, 'load', () => {
      renderer.setElementStyle(
        element.nativeElement,
        'height',
        element.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight + 'px'
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Microsoft Edge 35 is ignoring srcdoc property, any ideas about what's the problem?

I also accept workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason attribute does not work:

```
<iframe #frame></iframe>

import * as srcDoc from 'srcdoc-polyfill';

@ViewChild('frame')
public iframe:ElementRef;

srcDoc.set(this.iframe.nativeElement, "<html><body>test</body></html>");
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Note that you are technically _not_ polyfilling it in this example but rather _ponyfilling_ it (sometimes I hate the term of art), so this approach would be good in library code, but importing it as `import 'srcdoc-polyfill'` would be nicer in app code, as that is kind of the point of polyfills. Btw, upvoted!

Comment: I guess it polyfills only those iframes that exists on page when polyfill is executed.

Comment: No it does not polyfill anything, which is OK. You are importing the behavior that would be polyfilled and calling it as a function.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes it does polyfill already existing iframes with srcdoc attribute: https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill#usage

Comment: @Stoffe good catch. I looked at the source and... the UMD wrapper is completely non-standard. It appears to register globally _unless_ it detects an AMD environment in which case it just calls `define`. This means that, CommonJS environments will be polyfilled even if they import it. It will behave better in AMD environments. Needless to say this is very bad and surprising behavior... think I'm going to file an issue.

Comment: how do we add a force attribute to this i am using it with sandbox property but it dosent trigger the same @kemsky